# Flutter Terminal not working correctly in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I wanted to start learning flutter recently, so I set everything up, and code wise its going fine, but I have one major issue regarding the terminal in VS Code: Once I type any kind of command (for example: "flutter pub add ...") it doesn't do what its supposed to do but instead asks me how I want to open this file. There is no error message and other than this nothing happens. If I choose "VS Code" or "Text Editor" as an app to open the file with it simply shows my a blank text field.
I am using Windows 11.

Comment: Do this problem only happens in vscode? If you try in the powershell or in the prompt does it work? You should also check if the flutter path is in the environment variables.

Comment: I has no idea what the problem is, but my guess is that you did not open the folder. vs code is like the file explorer you need to specify the directory (folder) of your project, if you opened the file it will just open in a pre specified directory not the project

Comment: It isn't just in VS code but also in the normal Terminal. I have added flutter already to Path and the directory should be the right one from the project.